# How do i copy material from one .blend file to another?

Tags: append

I have two different files (rigs) which I would like to append one to the other, I did this by appending the object of one. Although now the material of this object is missing. How do i append it?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to BSE! Please add more information and screenshots. This will help people answer your question better. You can also upload your .blend file(s) to BSE's very own system called [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).

Comment: When you appended the object, blender also should of taken the material too. You may have some other problem here.

Answer (score 17):

You append Materials like everything else in Blender:

- In your new blend file, go to append:[image: Append menu]
- Select the blend file with the original material, and click "Append" to browse its contents.
- In it, go to the folder called "Material" (or "Mesh" or "Object" or "Texture" or something else depending on what you want to append) [image: inside a blend file]
- Select the materials (meshes, objects, textures, ...) you want to import and hit "append from library".