# How to import a grease pencil draw into another grease pencil file?

Tags: grease-pencil

I want to copy a 3D wire frame I made by grease pencil and paste or import it into another 3D wire flame. so that I can compare those two...work on both of them in the same 2D animation tab
Don't know how to do it...

blender 2.8  Mac pro user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm just a beginner, but if what you wish to bring into your new blender work area is a .blend file, you can "append" (otherwise known as import) the file from the File menu in the upper left.  I believe that you must be in "Object" mode when doing so.  If I'm wrong or I misunderstood, my apologies.  Perhaps this will help:  [Additional link info](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55943/how-do-i-copy-material-from-one-blend-file-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

#### [To add Blender Grease Pencil animations to a different file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133117/how-to-import-a-grease-pencil-draw-into-another-grease-pencil-file):

- Open the file you wish to import *into*
- Click File --> Append
- Find and double-click the Grease Pencil .blend File you want to import
- A new menu of directories pops up, select **`COLLECTION`** -->
- Select the specific collection that contains your grease pencil drawing
- Done, you should now see your Grease Pencil drawing inside the new .blend file

Reference:

[*How To Import Grease Pencil Object*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxlQxfXV_fU)